# How to get the functions (adresses) from a .DLL (Windows) to call them from Masm32

Tags: dll, masm32

Im writing a Compiler for a Pascal-like language which converts the program in **Masm32** (and then to a .exe). My goal is to let the coder **include Windows Libraries (.DLL)**. So I need to read out the functionnames and the jump adresses first for correct compiler warnings. (function not defined...)

Is there a way to do this? I heard that each Win32 function has a magic number (0xXXXXXXXX) which is the adress to it which then can be called with **call 0xXXXXXXXX**

Comment: That's the job of the linker.  Declare the function EXTERN in your asm.

Answer (score 0):

Masm32 comes with .inc files that include most of the Windows API functions and structures.  Perhaps you can leverage those?